# linux video codecs error, movies in black and white hue

Tags: ubuntu, video, codec

i have an ubuntu 9 installed on my desktop and recently  started getting an unusual error when i watch a movie. It doesn't matter what player i use i see the movie in black and white hue.

I try'ed installing the codecs again but that didn't worked.

Any ideas ? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer :D .. it was a problem with the gnome streamer properties.
It seems to be a documented bug [here](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/totem/+question/7373)
Also tutorial for fix are [here](http://portablejim.site-hosts.net/tips/75-vlc-hue-wrong.html)